# Mongoose is saving only objectId instead of the object data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend, nodemon

So I am trying to make users coaches by changing their role in the user model from user to coach.
Below is the user model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstname : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    lastname : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique : true
    },
    verified : {
        type : Boolean,
        default : false
    },
    password : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        minLength : 3
    },
    role : {
        type : String,
        enum : ['admin', 'coach', 'user'],
        default : 'user'
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

And below here is the coach model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const CoachSchema = new Schema({
    coach : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'User'
    },
    team : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Team'
    }
    
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Coach', CoachSchema)
```

On creation of a new coach, the ID of that particular user is passed in the params and then the role data in the user model is switched to coach.
The controller for the coach is below :

```
const Coach = require('../models/Coach')
const User = require('../models/User')
const Team = require('../models/Teams')


exports.createCoach = async (req, res)=>{
    try {
        const userId = req.params.id
        const coach_data = await User.findById(userId)
        const {password, verified, ...other} = coach_data._doc
        console.log(other);
        const team = req.body.team
        const team_data = await Team.findById(team)

        const user = await User.findById(userId)
        if(!user) return res.status(400).json({
            error : 'User not found'
        })
        
        const coach = new Coach({
            coach : other,
            team : team_data
        })

        if(user.role === 'coach') return res.status(404).json({
            error : 'User is already a coach'
        })

        

        const updateUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id : userId}, {
            role : 'coach'
        },
        {
            new : true
        }
        )


        await coach.save()
        res.status(200).json('User has been made coach')

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json(error)
    }
}

exports.getAllCoaches = async(req, res)=>{
    try {
        const coaches = await Coach.find()

        res.status(200).json(coaches)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error)
    }
}
```

And this is the router for the coach:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const coachController = require('../controllers/coachController')

router.post('/create-coach/:id', coachController.createCoach)
router.get('/get-coaches', coachController.getAllCoaches)

module.exports = router
```

This is what my databse now looks like
[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WclF.png[1]

Answer (score 1):

It is supossed to store a reference to the object `mongoose` can on querying the data fill this reference with the data using `.populate` if you have some experience with SQL it is like a `foreign key`.

Comment: Please can you explain more , i am new to node js so i do not really understand.

Comment: Please can you give show me a sample code if you have some

Comment: it has some explaination on the mongoose website over here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: I don't have personal examples that are public sadly